# Redirect site by keeping client browser static

Tags: windows, redirect, iis

I am trying to rewrite a URL by keeping the URL on client browser static and internally redirect to different pool. My scenario is

user types in www.test.com/myfilter in his browser, IIS rewrite rule should keep the URL in client browser the same, but deliver site content from www.diffsite.com/myfilter.

How do i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need ARR module and set up a reverse proxy as described [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)